# iOS 13 - captureOutput is never called

Tags: objective-c

I've been looking way to fix this problem, and sadly I can't: the delegate just is never being called. I tried so many possible ways none of them work.

Here is the code that is used

```
#import "headers/FMDManager.h"

@implementation capture

- (AVCaptureDevice *)frontFacingCameraIfAvailable
{
    NSArray *videoDevices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    AVCaptureDevice *captureDevice = nil;
    for (AVCaptureDevice *device in videoDevices){
        if (device.position == AVCaptureDevicePositionFront){
            captureDevice = device;
            break;
        }
    }
    return captureDevice;
}

- (AVCaptureDevice *)backFacingCameraIfAvailable
{
    NSArray *videoDevices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    AVCaptureDevice *captureDevice = nil;
    for (AVCaptureDevice *device in videoDevices){
        if (device.position == AVCaptureDevicePositionBack){
            captureDevice = device;
            break;
        }
    }
    return captureDevice;
}

- (void)setupCaptureSession:(BOOL)isfront{
    self.session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    self.session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;

    AVCaptureDevice *device = nil;
    NSError *error = nil;

    if (isfront){
        device = [self frontFacingCameraIfAvailable];
    } else {
        device = [self backFacingCameraIfAvailable];
    }

    AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&error];

    if (!input) {
        // Handle the error appropriately.
        NSLog(@"FMDLog - ERROR: trying to open camera: %@", error);
        exit(0);
    }

    self.photoOutput = [[AVCapturePhotoOutput alloc] init];
    self.photoOutput.highResolutionCaptureEnabled = YES;
    self.photoOutput.livePhotoCaptureEnabled = NO;

    if ([self.session canAddInput:input] && [self.session canAddOutput:self.photoOutput]) {
        [self.session addInput:input];
        [self.session addOutput:self.photoOutput];
        [self.session startRunning];
        NSLog(@"FMDLog - CaptureSession is now running.");
    }

}

- (void)takePhoto {
    NSLog(@"FMDLog - Session Status: %@", self.session);
    NSLog(@"FMDLog - TAKING PICTURE...");
    AVCapturePhotoSettings *settings = [[AVCapturePhotoSettings alloc] init];
    settings.highResolutionPhotoEnabled = YES;
    [self.photoOutput capturePhotoWithSettings:settings delegate:self];
    NSLog(@"FMDLog - DONE TAKING PICTURE!");
}

#pragma mark - AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCapturePhotoOutput *)output didFinishProcessingPhoto:(AVCapturePhoto *)photo error:(NSError *)error {  

    NSLog(@"FMDLog - captureOutput is now running.");
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"error : %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }
    NSData *imageData = [photo fileDataRepresentation];
    if (imageData) {
        printf("Saving image to %s...\n", [filepath UTF8String]);
        NSLog(@"FMDLog - saving image...");
        [imageData writeToFile:filepath atomically:YES];
    }
    NSLog(@"FMDLog - captureOutput is now ended.");
    [self.session stopRunning];

}

- (void)setfilename:(NSString *)filename {
    filepath = filename;
}


// NEW
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCapturePhotoOutput *)captureOutput didFinishRecordingLivePhotoMovieForEventualFileAtURL:(NSURL *)outputFileURL resolvedSettings:(AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings *)resolvedSettings
{
    NSLog(@"FMDLog - NEW METHOD 1");
}

- (void)captureOutput:(AVCapturePhotoOutput *)captureOutput didFinishProcessingLivePhotoToMovieFileAtURL:(NSURL *)outputFileURL duration:(CMTime)duration photoDisplayTime:(CMTime)photoDisplayTime resolvedSettings:(AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings *)resolvedSettings error:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"FMDLog - NEW METHOD 2");
}

- (void)captureOutput:(AVCapturePhotoOutput *)captureOutput didFinishCaptureForResolvedSettings:(AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings *)resolvedSettings error:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"FMDLog - NEW METHOD 3");
}

-(void)captureOutput:(AVCapturePhotoOutput *)captureOutput didFinishProcessingPhotoSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)photoSampleBuffer previewPhotoSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)previewPhotoSampleBuffer resolvedSettings:(AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings *)resolvedSettings bracketSettings:(AVCaptureBracketedStillImageSettings *)bracketSettings error:(NSError *)error {

    NSLog(@"FMDLog - NEW METHOD 4");
}

@end
```

Headers

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

// To take Picture
@interface capture : NSObject<AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate> {
    NSString *filepath;
}

@property (nonatomic,strong) AVCaptureSession *session;
@property (readwrite,retain) AVCapturePhotoOutput *photoOutput;
// @property (nonatomic, copy) void(^returnBlock)(UIImage* image);

- (AVCaptureDevice *)frontFacingCameraIfAvailable;
- (void)setfilename:(NSString *)filename;
- (void)setupCaptureSession:(BOOL)isfront;
- (void)takePhoto;
// - (void)captureWithBlock:(void(^)(UIImage* image))block;

@end
```